# Why were my edits correcting grammar rejected?

Tags: discussion

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1512035

I concede I might've edited too much text, but undoubtedly the OP made typos. Saxon genitives are missing.

> The problem is  **Bertsekas** book is introductory while **Ross** book explains expression $E[\ E[X\mid Y] \ ]$ just by briefly saying it is a function of $y$ if I **remeber** correctly.

2. https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1512036

"i" as a pronoun must be capitalized.

> How do i develop a very good conception in probability theory to do advanced theoretical research in communication theory? Which book do i follow to gain a solid conception about the subject.I have the original manuscript of A N Kolmogorov but do not have the mathematical background to understand it.

3. https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1512051

I emboldened the grammatical mistakes.

> Tomorrow I will begin my studies, real analysis, however I have some difficulties in making statements so I thought **before starting the study in real analysis, learn how to do demonstrations properly**.

> I know only learn by doing, but **use a book as support** would be of great help,

4. https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1512603

> https://www.math.ubc.ca/~angel/probab/

This URL is broken, but the post doesn't say so.

> Exercises with solutions for probability theory?

The title is deceptive. OP is talking about measure-theoretic probability theory, not just introductory probability theory.

Comment: in your second case ,I wouldnt say just capitalising  'i' would count as a siginificant edit.I usually reject such edits as 'no improvement or so whatever' criterion

Comment: People tend to dislike edits on old posts, especially if those edits only correct the language and formatting.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see your point, but I think it's OK to edit old posts to fix the links.  I remember the diamond Community user once did that with a script as consequence of the domain name change of Math.Meta.SE.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Those scripts don't bump the posts. So incomparable. That being said, I agree that links should be kept up to date.

Comment: All the suggested edits you link to could be reasonably rejected.  You leave out some context.  And the single time you capitalize i to read "I" is insufficient for suggesting an edit.